# XML schema on type substitution

Tags: xml, schema

i have an XML file like below and wanted to create an XML schema using type substitution method so that it can validate the below XML file. But the schema that i created is totally wrong.please show me how to code the schema to validate the file XML below.

Details:

- there are only two types of animals being stored one is bird and one is fish.
- for both type, name and origin element is required
- for type:bird, additional color element can be optionally stored.
- for type:fish, additional size element is required to be store

  ```
  <animals>
   <animal animalID="b-1" xsi:type="bird">
       <name>Humming Bird</name>
       <origin>Asia</origin>
       <color>Blue</color>
   </animal> 
   <animal animalID="b-2" xsi:type="bird">
       <name>Horn Bill</name>
       <origin>Asia</origin>
   </animal>
   <animal animalID="f-2" xsi:type="fish">
       <name>Whale</name>
       <origin>Europe</origin>
       <size>Large</size>
   </animal>
   <animal animalID="b-5" xsi:type="bird">
       <name>Parrot</name>
       <origin>Europe</origin>
   </animal>
  ```

i have come out with the below schema and i think its totally wrong.

```
 <xsd:element name="bird" substitutionGroup="animals" 
         type="birdType"/>
 <xsd:element name="fish" substitutionGroup="animals" 
         type="fishType"/>
 <xsd:element name="animals">
<xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="animal" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>

 <xsd:element name="animal">
<xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element ref="bird" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm no biologist, but if I were I would quarrel with your taxonomy...

If you're using xsi:type to distinguish the two types, then the schema needs to contain global complex type definitions named "bird" and "fish". You can derive both of these by extension from some base type, say "creature" (since we're not doing real biology here...). The type creature contains the two common elements name and origin, and the two extensions contain the optional elements color and size respectively. The animal element is defined to be of type "creature".

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="unqualified">
<xsd:complexType name="animalType">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xsd:element name="origin" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="birdType">
    <xsd:complexContent>
        <xsd:extension base="animalType">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="color" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="fishType">
    <xsd:complexContent>
        <xsd:extension base="animalType">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="size" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:element name="animals">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="animal" type="animalType" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```